# Convert html strings with backslashes in JAVA

Tags: java

How to convert the following string with backslashes to the string below? Is there a function in JAVA to do so or i have to use replace?

```
'<div class=\”divcontent\"><p style=\"padding:0px;\"><p><strong>title<\/strong><\/p><\/div>’

<div class=”divcontent"><p style="padding:0px;"><p><strong>title</strong></p></div>’
```

Comment: you want to put those components in string variable ?.

Comment: string replace do the work

Comment: Use String.Replace('\','"');

Comment: I don't understand. Do you get a `String` containing these backslashes or are you seeing the `String` with backslashes in your debugger or something?

Comment: It looks like me they are the Escape characters because there are " characters in your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use `replaceAll` method :

Java String Replace Variant ‘`replaceAll`’

Unlike the ‘`replace`’ method, ‘`replaceAll`’ supports regular expressions. The capability of ‘`replaceAll`’ makes the complex search of substrings possible within a string object. After a search, each matched substring is replaced with the given replacement.  The following is a format of ‘`replaceAll`’ method:

```
String replaceAll (String regEx, String replacement)


String sampleString = new String ("Remove All backslashes");

String resultantString = sampleString.replaceAll ("\\","");
```

[See this java replace and replaceAll method](https://www.udemy.com/blog/java-string-replace/)

Comment: Or even easier: `sampleString.replace('\\', '\0');`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, is that replace all occurences of backslashes?

Comment: Yes, but it only takes a single `char` to replace (fixed code in that comment as well).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html)'s [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#UNESCAPE_JAVA) method.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
// ...
String html = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("<div class=\"divcontent\"><p style=\"padding:0px;\"><p><strong>title<\/strong><\/p><\/div>");
```

Why do not we use unescapeHtml() method? Because, for example, it tries to convert `&lt;` to `<` and `&gt;` to `>`. But we do not have any issue with them. Easily we want to remove standard java escape sequences.

Comment: Tested in eclipse and doesn't compile.